# OpenLdap slapd how to query multiple DIT with a single ldapsearch

Tags: slapd

I have an open ldap server, `slapd`, serving two DITs

- first is a completely local tree, `ou=People,dc=local,dc=company,dc=org` because we have some external users in our department
- second is a translucent overlay to the company's ldap `ou=People,dc=company,dc=org` with lots of additional local attributes

I have the completely local subtree because translucent overlay **can** create local entries with no parent, but then you can't access it except with slapcat (or a method I did not figure out yet).

This is completely functional **BUT**
now, when searching for a user I would have to send two different searches, first with

```
ldapsearch -b ou=People,dc=local,dc=company,dc=org uid=user1
```

and second

```
ldapsearch -b ou=People,dc=company,dc=org uid=user1
```

in case the first search did not find anything.

Would it be possible to configure the server in a way that both trees are searched at once? Does any existent overlay give me this functionality, and if yes: how???

By the way: the uid is unique to both trees.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read on how to glue databases together under a common suffix with the  *subordinate* keyword.